# How can we introduce an anomaly class as a positive class to sklearn IsolationForest?

Tags: python, random-forest, anomaly-detection, confusion-matrix, isolation-forest

I inspired by this [notebook](https://github.com/elena-sharova/IsolationForest/blob/master/IsolationForest_v0.1.ipynb), and I'm experimenting `IsolationForest` (IF) algorithm using `scikit-learn==0.22.2.post1` for anomaly detection context on the **SF** version of [KDDCUP99 dataset](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.fetch_kddcup99.html#sklearn.datasets.fetch_kddcup99), including 4 attributes. The data is directly fetched from `sklearn` and after preprocessing (label encoding the categorical feature) passed to the IF algorithm with the default setup. Perhaps we can call our task is binary classification.

The full code is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66769476/inconsistency-between-contamination-set-up-and-number-of-outlier-prediction-in-s). There are two possibilities to demonstrate and evaluate IF results in the context of Anomaly/outlier detection. I think option A is my case, and I expect that `TP+FN = Anomaly/positive class` and `TN+FP = Normal/negative class`.

[image: img]

**Problem**: If you consider the following results on testset I realized that Sklearn IF algorithm treats normal data as *positive class* by default while the [*anomaly class* would be better to be considered as *positive class*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56894608/10452700) for evaluation via [confusion matrix](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html?highlight=confusion%20matrix#sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix). This result in incorrect output in confusion matrix as it is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56459660/does-majority-class-treated-as-positive-in-sklearn-sklearn-calculate-false-posi) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64887501/confusion-about-positive-class-and-sklearn-metric-pos-label-0).

[image: img]
[image: img]

You see that even though I tried IF with the real anomaly rate is 0.5% from documentation( I set `contamination=0.005`), the number of `FP` surprisingly increased (maybe it is `FN`)!! The legend on the left side has been designed based on results of `confusion_matrix`(from [documentation example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html?highlight=confusion%20matrix#sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix)) as it is printed at the bottom of each confusion matrix in the above picture.

```py
tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix(y_test_sf, y_pred_test).ravel()
print("TN: ",tn,"\nFP: ", fp,"\nFN: " ,fn,"\nTP: ", tp)
print("TP+FN: ",tp+fn,"\nTN+FP: ", tn+fp)
```

- **Quick solution:** is to introduce a legend for the confusion matrix, not to confuse us more!
  **Expected solution:** is to understand how to adjust the IF algorithm from the root to treat the Anomaly class as a *positive class*. I don't need to include legend and other calculation like `TP+FN = Anomaly class` and `TN+FP = Normal class` per se. I'm not sure it is the right way to force it to see those data with labels of `-1` normal, which are Anomaly and vice versa.

my last try was to play with `pos_label=-1` due to Score is biased towards the Anomaly class like we do when we configure `GridSearchCV`:

```
scoring = {'AUC': 'roc_auc', 'f1_score': make_scorer(f1_score, pos_label=-1)}
```

Probably I am missing something here, and perhaps there is an elegant way to fix it, and any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I like to look at Cohen’s kappa for confusion matrices.

Comment: The same unsolved problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56459660/does-majority-class-treated-as-positive-in-sklearn-sklearn-calculate-false-posi) working with classification with imbalanced data set using Sklearn, I'm not sure how *Cohen’s kappa* can help this issue.

Comment: In the output from the IsolationForest, replace 1 with 0 and then -1 with 1. Then use the standard metric calculations

Comment: @JonNordby thanks for your input, Actually It was one of my options to do it and hope it pass elements right and not treat *majority class* again as a positive class.

Comment: @Mario: You can make a function that checks for that, and then flips to use the correct class as positive class (always minority).